# Tener acceso a archivos externos en Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

He creado un proyecto en Angular 2 dentro de un proyecto JavaScript.

Necesito utilizar datos y objetos, dentro de esta aplicación de Angular, que se encuentran en archivos externos y no se pueden mover de allí.

Al hacer uso del comando del CLI `ng serve` y crear mi App en `http://localhost:4200/` los archivos, evidentemente no los recoge, aunque haciendo un `ng build --prod` de la aplicación esto se soluciona, pero entonces debo estar ejecutando este comando constantemente por cada cambio para ver los resultados reales con los archivos externos.

¿Hay alguna solución para hacer uso de estos archivos con sus datos y objetos durante la fase de pruebas, lo que sería el equivalente al `http://localhost:4200/`?

Comment: en cuanto a los datos puedes llamarlo por un servicio y no vas a tener problemas siempre y cuando sea un JSON; en cuanto a objetos no me queda claro a que te refieres con ello

Comment: En cuanto a objetos me refiero, que hay objetos declarados en dichos archivos y que pueden usarse globalmente en la aplicación y que necesitaré usar también dentro de la aplicación Angular. Estos objetos son creados a partir de varias dependencias de otros archivos, y por tanto necesito cargar todos estos archivos.

Comment: cuando hablas de objetos declarado te refieres a clases que estan en el programa y tu las quieres instanciar? si es asi solo tienes que hacer un vulgar <script src="http://mantequilla.com/miscript.js"></script>

Comment: subelo a git y luego lo llamas no vas a tener inconvenientes

Comment: Perfecto, voy a probar! A veces damos mas vueltas y no paramos en la solución mas sencilla! Gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No recoges los archivos desde el AngularCLI porque tienes que configurarlo para que lo haga. El procedimiento es sencillo.

En tu archivo angular-cli.json, cambia o añade esto:

```
...
"apps": [{
            "root": "src", // carpeta root
            "outDir": "dist",
            "assets": [
                "assets",
                "miarchivo.json",
                "micarpeta",
                "test/datos.js",
            ],
            ...
```

Esos archivos deben estar en la carpeta root.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alejandro! Que sencillo :)